# How to lock a sequence of methods, such that other thread call those same method should be waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose there is one Thread and it has a sequence of methods to be executed:

```
public void task(){
   method();
   method();
   method();
   method();
}
```

I would like to lock the whole sequence. That is, when that `task()` is executing, I don't want the other threads to execute the same `method()` but to wait until the whole `task()` is done. What kinds of lock is needed?

Comment: I recommend to use other type of architecture to do this, perceptibly by far it is wrong practice, it don't make a minimum sense. 

Think about to do an asynchronous methods or other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either make that task *synchronized*:

```
public synchronized void task() {
    method();
    method();
    method();
    method();
}
```

This will prevent other threads from calling the same `task()` method on the same object, including other `synchronized` methods on that object. You can have more control with an explicit `synchronized` statement, like

```
public void task() {
    synchronized (this) { // or another object
        method();
        method();
        method();
        method();
    }
}
```

Or use your own [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) instance:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public void task() {
    lock.lock();  // block until lock is released
    try {
        method();
        method();
        method();
        method();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

If you want to have all `method()` calls not to be running at the same time, just apply the same mechanism to the `method()` declaration:

```
public synchronized void method() // or one of the other two options
```

If you apply one of these three mechanisms to both `task` and `method`, you would make sure, that the thread calling `task()` will finish all `method()` calls sequentially and prevent other threads from calling any `method()` meanwhile. Both `synchronized` and the `ReentrantLock` allow the same thread to get the same lock/monitor multiple times (nested locks).

Finally, if you want to allow multiple parallel calls to `method()` but just not while `task()` is executed, you'd need a shared or read-write lock (see [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)).

Comment: Excuse me. This will block other thread which call the whole `task()`. What I want is to block thread to call  `method() ` until `task()` is done..Even I add synchronized to `method() `, It would just prevent  mutliple `method() ` run at the same time. It is possible that one call  `method() ` from other Thread B influence the order of ` task()` running in Thread A . e.g. the order may be : `method() (from Thread A) -> method() (from Thread A) -> method() (from Thread B) -> method() (from Thread A)  -> method() (from Thread A)` .. What I want is the` method()` order cannot be interrupted

Comment: If you add `synchronized` to both `task()` and `method()`, you would make sure, that the thread calling `task()` will finish all `method()` calls sequentially and prevent other threads from calling any `method()` meanwhile. Now if however you want to *allow* multiple calls to `method()` but just not while `task()` is executed, you'd need a shared or read-write lock (see `ReentrantReadWriteLock`).

Comment: oh..I realize now. If the `synchronized` block using same object to both `task()` and `method()`, it would achieve what I want. From `task()`, it would just acquire the same lock twice with no harm. Sorry for such a stupid question.

Comment: Can't see any stupidity here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be an option but may not be the best. You could modify the signature of your `method()` in this way:

```
public void method(int serialExecutionCount) {
    synchronized(this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < serialExecutionCount; i++) {
            // body of your method()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `task()` method will be like this:

```
public void task() {
   method(4);
}
```

Now, if you call it from other thread like this:

```
method(1);
```

it will wait for previous 4 method calls to be finished from `task()` method's calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a shared Lock of some kind, and pass it's reference to all threads that need to execute the sequence.

for instance, create a `public static final ReentrantLock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();` on the class which has the task() method and in the beginning of the method task() write `LOCK.lock();` and `LOCK.unlock();` at the end. now, all threads passing through the task() method will try to acquire the lock, and it will block them if its already taken.